# Hide text part of select element

Tags: html, css, angular, html-select

I have a `select` element in a sidebar.  The sidebar can be collapsed, which causes everything in it to change to icons.  When this happens, I want the select to only show the arrow button (which should still open the full dropdown when you click it), but the width doesn't go below a certain point and it still shows a small bit of empty white box (not connected to any padding or margins as far as I can tell).  Is there any way to do this?  The only related questions I can find are about hiding the button instead.

Markup:

```
<select [ngClass]="{'account-selector': !sidebarCollapsed, 'account-selector-collapsed': sidebarCollapsed}" [(ngModel)]="selectedAccount" (change)="setSelectedAccount()">
    <option *ngFor="let account of accounts" [ngValue]="account" [selected]="account === selectedAccount">{{account.data.Name}}</option>
</select>
```

CSS:

```
.account-selector {
    max-width: 90%;
}

.account-selector-collapsed {
    // what goes here?
}
```

Comment: did you try adding  `display: none` to it

Comment: @HimanshuArora That hides the whole thing, I still want to show the button part.

Comment: use the button selector then, something like : 
`.account-selector-collapsed button { display: none;}`

Comment: Sorry, my bad! I mis-read your ques. That would hide the button specifically

Comment: So, what you can do is, in the collapsed state hide the whole thing, and use a `div` which is styled to give the appearance as needed and shows up only when the sidebar is collapsed, and position it (perhaps using absolute) where you want your button to be visible. You can programmatically invoke the functionality of `select box` on its click.

Comment: @HimanshuArora Unfortunately it looks like there isn't a built-in way to open a select from another element.  All the workarounds are really ugly hacks and/or browser-specific, so I might be able to make that work but I'd prefer another solution.

Comment: Could you make a brief plunker?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Got it working with this CSS:

```
.account-selector-collapsed {
    cursor: pointer;
    width: 15px;
    height: 15px;
    font-size: 0; // hides the text for the current selection
    border: 0;
    background: white; // TODO: replace with an appropriate image
    -moz-appearance: none;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
}
.account-selector-collapsed::-ms-expand {
    display: none;
}
```

The key is `-moz/webkit-appearance: none;`, which essentially turns it into a plain text box that can be freely styled, with `::-ms-expand` serving a similar purpose on IE/Edge.  I haven't been able to test the latter too thoroughly (I'm working on a Mac and my Windows VM is having problems), but it seems to work there from what I've been able to test, and definitely works for other browsers.

Answer (score 0):

Not having the plunker to see how it behaves, I can only guess that you need to do:

```
.account-selector-collapsed {
    width: calc( 90% - 10px) /*change 10px to suite your need*/
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I spent a lot of time trying to make `select` element styled.
Unfortunately it is impossible at the moment. Each browser has its own way to render the native `select` box element, even if you styled it with `css`.

As I see you using Angular 4 (2). It is very simple to make your own `select` with only `<div>` or whatever element you want.

Here some example of implementation.

`select.component.html`:

```
    <div class="select-options">
      <div
        class="select-option"
        *ngFor="let option of options"
        [attr.data-value]="option.id"
        [class.selected]="option.active"
        [innerText]="option.title"
        (click)="selectOption(option.id);"
      >
      </div>
    </div>
```

`select.component.ts`:

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-select',
  templateUrl: './select.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./select.component.scss']
})
export class SelectComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() options: Array<any> = [];

  constructor() {}

  ngOnInit() {

  }

  selectOption(optionId) {
    this.options.map(option => period.active = option.id === optionId);
  }
}
```